# !Blank on visible property of icon in gallery

Tags: powerapps

Having a bit of trouble getting a tick to appear visible in a gallery if the user has made a selection in a drop down column in the edit details screen.

Just a bit of background. I have created a share-point list of my data. The dropdown selection I would like my users to fill out is a choices field within my share-point list. The selections appear correctly and are written to sharepoint when the selection is made.

However when i try to call my choices field in the visibility field i get errors. I've tried all sorts of permutations to figure it out but just can't. I've tried in the visible property of the tickbox to do.

**Calling the item**:
If(!IsBlank(ThisItem.Validation_Status_),true, false)

**Calling the Datafield**:
If(!IsBlank("Validation_x0020_Status"),true, false)

**Calling the DataCard**:
If(!IsBlank(DataCardValue22.Selected),true, false)

The weird thing is that I cant even call the choices field as an item within my gallery, does any one know how i can check to see if that field has been filled in per gallery item. At the this point the solution doesn't need to be tick box visibility,  just a "yes" or "no" if it has been filled out would be great as well!

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a challenging to visualize what you are looking for, but I think you want a Checkbox control, in a Gallery to show `true` if the column in Sharepoint is `true` and `false` if the column is `false`.

**You'll want to focus on the `Default` property of the Checkbox.**

Set the `Default` property to:

```
If(ThisItem.ColumnName = X, true, false)
```

Where `ColumnName` is the Sharepoint column and `X` is the affirmative value in the column. You can also use `!IsBlank` or any logic operator you want `<,>,=` etc.

**Heres a quick example:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I think this would work but the issue im having is that the column i am trying to check gets the error "Name isnt valid, this identifier isnt recognised", when I   insert it into your formula. Have had the same issue when trying other formulas.  In my sharepoint list the column I am trying to check is a choices field, would that be the cause of the issue? I am just trying to have some sort of notification that the row in the gallery has been completed by the user because they have selected and saved their choice in edit screen of the gallery.

Comment: Turns out I was trying to do too much with too many data sources in the same gallery. Works perfect after I gave both data sources their own gallery.